# Unable to access internet on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. I am now unable to access Internet (wired). I tried things like renewing the IP address, etc. but that did not seem to work. It recognizes whether the lan cable is plugged in or not but, still I cannot access the Internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the outputs for the commands:

```
$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:fe:59:71:3e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:feff:fe59:713e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:139639 (139.6 KB)  TX bytes:102684 (102.6 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Memory:f0400000-f0420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:219840 (219.8 KB)  TX bytes:219840 (219.8 KB)

$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet)"

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566DM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:104a] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2800]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide more information - keep in mind that we can't see your screen - so we need more to have your question answerable. For example, include the output of `ifconfig` and `route -n` (from a terminal) after the connection has reported to be established. Also  the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet)"` would be valuable. If you can't get connected to the internet on an alternative way, try to copy the output to another machine to include it in your answer, e.g. by using a USB flash drive to transfer the exact text.

Comment: Can you communicate (e.g., with `ping`) with any other machine on the LAN?

Answer (score 0):

Type `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type `echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

After that, logout your machine, pull out the ethernet cable and then plug it in again after logging it in. This should work